# Reproject one raster onto another (port from R to Python)

Tags: python, r

In R I can easily create a raster with the raster package and then transform that raster into another, I am attaching a simple example extracted from my code.

```
r <- raster(index[c(nrow:1),])
extent(r) <- c(lon[1] - dx/2, rev(lon)[1] + dx/2, lat[1] - dy/2, rev(lat)[1] + dy/2)
crs(r) <- crs(paste0("+init=epsg:", epsg))
r.ok <- raster(ncol=256*(x2[1]-x1[1]+1), nrow=256*(x2[2]-x1[2]+1), crs = CRS("+init=epsg:3857"))
extent(r.ok) <- c(floor(bounds1[1]), floor(bounds2[3]), floor(bounds2[2]), floor(bounds1[4]))
r.crs.ok <- projectRaster(from=r, to=r.ok, method="ngb")
```

And one that does nothing but simpler

```
data <- array(1:1000, c(10, 100))
r <- raster(data)
extent(r) <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
crs(r) <- CRS("+init=epsg:3857")
r.ok <- raster(ncol=200, nrow=300, crs = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))
extent(r.ok) <- c(10, 20, 30, 40)
r.crs.ok <- projectRaster(from=r, to=r.ok, method="ngb")
```

I'm porting a function from R to Python, and I don't see how to do something like that. I have tried GeoDataFrame but it seems to treat the points as separate things instead of a raster. With osgeo, it seems that all the time I have to read and write files. Any ideas?

Comment: What about using `GDAL` directly? https://gdal.org/api/python.html

Comment: I have tried with osgeo and its modules, including gdal for several days, but I have not been able to do what I say.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. `Error: object 'lon' not found`

Comment: In what sense does it not work? The projection of `r.crs.ok` is the same as that of `r.ok`.  It seems to work as expected

Comment: The two rasters are different, they do not have the same number of rows and columns, for example. The CRS is usually different too. r.crs.ok has the data from r transformed to fit into r.ok.

Comment: This is expected. The function sets the extent and resolution of the new object to match the `to` raster.  If you only want to change the projection then try `r.crs.ok <- projectRaster(from=r, crs=crs(r.ok), method="ngb")`.  If you want fine control over final extent resolution and crs, then use GDAL directly, as already suggested.

Comment: I appreciate the help in porting this code to Python, but after hundreds of tests, your words are not clear to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241420/discussion-between-fergusrg-and-dww).

Answer (score 0):

`rasterio`, `gdal` and `rioxarray` are some of the libraries available in python to work with raster images. You can check the documentations of these libraries to get a better understanding.

But there is no single library in python for working with raster images which has got all the required modules. You may have to club multiple libraries and sometimes you may have to do one task with `gdal` and then save its output then again you may have to read the saved output using some other library to continue the analysis.

You can check this [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37238/writing-numpy-array-to-raster-file) and see if it's related to your query.